# Firebase in node.js not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I am facing some issues to implement firebase in node. Below is the code I am trying to run on node.

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./service_account.json");

admin.initializeApp({
     credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
     databaseURL: "https://<myfirebasedb>.firebaseio.com/"
});

var Queue = require('firebase-queue')

firebase.initializeApp({
    databaseURL: "https://<myfirebasedb>.firebaseio.com/"
});

//start your worker here. "users" is a table in my db which has users.
var ref = firebase.database().ref('users');
var queue = new Queue(ref, function(data, progress, resolve, reject) {
  // Read and process task data
  console.log(" Inside I am!! ")
  console.log(data);

  // Do some work
  progress(50);

  // Finish the task asynchronously
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve();
  }, 1000);
});

console.log(" hello world ")
```

Seems my code never runs. It only prints the "hello world" which is the last line.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code never runs is because Cloud functions for firebase works on events triggered by Firebase features or HTTPS requests. Your code is just sitting there and never gets called.

Check out the firebase documentation and especially the section about "Writing Functions"

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Comment: Thanks @Clinton. What google suggests is a paid solution.